# Creating a linked list of objects

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a class assignment (read: no use of the STL) where I need to create a sorted linked list of objects, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this.

The class that I am using contains both integer and string members, but it is only one of these integer members that will be sorted. I currently have a fully functioning linked list template that will successfully run with integer data.

Now my problem lies in converting this to work with my class. When instantiating this linked list, a `<Type>` must be defined, in this case that type is `Poster`, after the class Poster that I am sorting. However, in the declaration of the linked list class, there is a declaration and definition of the `class Node` which reads

```
class Node
{
public:
    Type Element;
    Node *Next, *Previous;

    Node() : Next(NULL), Previous(NULL) {} // Default constructor
    Node (Type Data, Node *PNode = NULL) : // Non-default constructor
        Element (Data),
        Next (PNode),
        Previous (PNode) {}
};
```

I'm unsure how this existing definition will work when the members of `Poster` are introduced when `LinkedList<Poster> listOfPosters` is declared. Should I replace the above definition of `Node` with the contents of `class Poster`, or will `Type Element` in the node be marked as a sort of catch-all container for the members of `class Poster`, so that members of `Poster` can be accessible via `Element.GetMemberValue()`?

Comment: Hint: `class Node` needs to be a template much as `LinkedList` is.

Comment: Look into Templated classes, which your teacher likely covered. A linked list should be able to handle any arbitrary data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing that the declaration of the LinkedList class looks something like

```
template<class Type>
class LinkedList
{ ... }
```

When the program that uses the linked list class (the main program) instantiates a LinkedList class like following

```
LinkedList<Poster> myLinkedList;
```

The compiler, at compile time, generates code from the template, and replaces all occurrences of "Type" with "Poster". Therefore, you dont need to change the linked-list or node class.

Answer (score 1):

The `Node.Element` member will store a (by-value) copy of the `Poster`. There is no need to manually replace anything in the definition of Node; that's the whole point of C++ templates.

When you declare a `LinkedList<Poster>` object, the compiler will generate a new class and substitute all instances of the `Type` placeholder with `Poster`. This will automatically create an appropriate `Node` class inside the `LinkedList<Poster>` class that represents nodes which hold a `Poster` object.